# Deploying iPad Application without using App-Store

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I have 1 Question can we deploy our iPad application onto 500 users iPad without using AppStore.

I know about the developer license but it allows only 100 UDID per License so can we increase the number of UDID. So that we can deploy our applications.

Thanks

Rick Jackson

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. By using the "Enterprise program": http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: but where its written that we can add more than 100 UDID inside enterprise license

Comment: I don't see why there should be a limit of 100. This is *not* the same as testing with up to 100 devices. BTW, the program is mainly targeted at big companies providing solutions to their employees.

Comment: The 100 limit is for ad-hoc distribution. In the enterprise license you've got the In-House distribution as well (in that case the number of devices is not limited).

Comment: ok.... As your saying i can distribute my applications using in-House distribution but if i want to distribute outside using inhouse is that we can do ?

Comment: I'm afraid, there is no "official" way to do that - what scenario do you have in mind?

Comment: Eiko Tell Me 1 thing I was googling around the forums I have found the below information Tell me whether i am correct or wrong 

1. Apple Developer License = 99$ (Which we already purchaed) Ad-Hoc Distribution : Only up to 100 devices can    be used for testing (i.e. used in "developer mode") and moreover, the app will vanish after 3 months.

2. Apple Enterprise License = 299$ This have New Feature known as In-House Distribution after googling i have found the below Information:

Comment: "In-House Distribution : iPhone apps provisioned using the enterprise distribution method are not submitted  to the App Store. In-house apps can be hosted on a website, file sharing system, or simply emailed  directly to users. Installation for the user is as simple as syncing with iTunes and it can be  distributed over 500 devices. But after googling here is the catch i have found

Comment: "You can't distribute your application outside of the company because it is a violation of section 2.2 of
  your iPhone SDK license agreement. The enterprise version has an exemption that allows you to bypass the   store for distribution to other devices within a single organization (as determined by the presence of a   Unique DUNS number). Also, this is not a legal issue, it is a civil contract issue. You won't go to jail if   you break the rules, but you can (and will) have your SDK license and developer keys revoked."

Comment: This looks like what I've read. If you have a very specific need, you might contact Apple directly to see if they are ok with it.

Comment: Thanks Eiko For helping me.... i have contacted apple for this and waiting for there reply.... if i got the email from them i will post the answer i got from them..... Thank you all who helped me........